# Score counter for a Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: python

So I am trying to put a score counter on this game of rock paper scissors. I would love some help

```
import random
import math

fox = random.randint(0,900)


print '*' * 50
print ' ' * 10, 'Welcome To Rock Paper Scissors!'
print '*' * 50
opener = raw_input('DO YOU THINK YOU HAVE WHAT IT TAKES!!!')
#opener2 = 
zero = int(0)
num_rounds_won = zero



def thrower1(fox): 
    fox = random.randint(0,900)
    if fox <= 300:
        return 'r'
    elif 300 < fox <= 600:
        return 's'
    else: 
        return 'p'

rd1 = thrower1(fox)
while True:
    choose = str(raw_input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"))
    choice = choose.lower()[0:1]#
    raw_input("play again?")
        if yes ref()

def ref(choice, rd1):
    if choice == 'r' and rd1 == 'p':
        return num_rounds_won + 1
    elif choice == 'p' and rd1 == 'r':
        return num_rounds_won + 1
    elif choice == 's' and rd1 == 'p':
        return num_rounds_won + 1
    elif choice == rd1:
        return "Draw"
    else:
        return "I Win!"


results = ref(choice, rd1)
print results
print num_rounds_won + 1
```

Comment: add your code to your question and some details about what is wrong with your code. Also I only see python so the other tags are nt relevant

Comment: what is `if yes ref()` meant to be doing?

Comment: So what is your question? `wins+=1` works. Otherwise, `wins=itertools.count(0); next(wins)`

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up your code (you tried to call ref() before defining it!) hoping that it will help you,

```
import random
import math

fox = random.randint(0,900)


print '*' * 50
print ' ' * 10, 'Welcome To Rock Paper Scissors!'
print '*' * 50
opener = raw_input('DO YOU THINK YOU HAVE WHAT IT TAKES!!!')
#opener2 = 
zero = int(0)
num_rounds_won = zero  

def thrower1(fox): 
    fox = random.randint(0,900)
    if fox <= 300:
        return 'r'
    elif 300 < fox <= 600:
        return 's'
    else: 
        return 'p'

def ref(choice, rd1):
    if choice == 'r' and rd1 == 'p':
        print "you won"
        return 1
    elif choice == 'p' and rd1 == 'r':
        print "you won"
        return 1
    elif choice == 's' and rd1 == 'p':
        print "you won"
        return 1
    elif choice == rd1:
        print "Draw"
        return 0
    else:
        print "I Win!"
        return 0

while True:
    rd1 = thrower1(fox)
    choose = str(raw_input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"))
    choice = choose.lower()[0:1]#
    num_rounds_won += ref(choice, rd1)
    play_again = raw_input("play again(y/n)?")
    if play_again == "y":
        continue
    else:
        break

print "you won", num_rounds_won, "games"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your problem is, this is a complete shot in the dark but I see a few problems that I think will need to be fixed.

First, it's important to know that Python is a scripting language. It reads code as it runs it, 1 line at a time. If you try to call a function before you define it I will be an error (this is not the case in compiled languages like Java). This is why you should put all your definitions at the top of your file (below your imports). This has 2 advantages. 1) All your definitions are handled first thing you and don't need to worry about them. 2) all your functions are in one place and easy to find, not stuck in the middle of the code.

You try to use `ref()` before you define it. This will cause an error. Also, your `ref()` has 2 arguments (`choice` and `rd1`) but you call it with no arguments. This is also an error.

Another issue is that your `while True` loop will never ever exit so NOTHING you write below this loop will ever be read nor run by Python. You need to make this loop the absolute last part of your code (or add a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement)

Comment: One extra note on the "Python must see definitions before it can use the function" thing. `def` doesn't run the code, it just creates the definition so you can have undefined functions *inside a definition* BUT they must be defined before you try to execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

I also took a quick look at this one. I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but there are a ton of ways that you could keep track of the score. In your case the easiest way to keep track of the score would be to just create a list with three elements (i.e. [0, 0, 0]). Whenever a user wins, loses, or has a draw in the game you'd add one to a specific position in the list.

I've also pasted a different way to accomplish this same task using a class the keep track of the game. This class could be easily modified to provide the user experience you're needing for your specific game.

```
from random import choice

class RockPaperScissors(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('{0}\nWelcome to Rock Paper Scissors!\n{0}'.format('*' * 30))
        self.score = {'wins':0, 'losses':0, 'draws':0}
        self.choices = {'r':'Rock', 'p':'Paper', 's':'Scissors'}
        self.winningCombos = (('Rock','Scissors'), ('Paper','Rock'), ('Scissors','Paper'))
        self.errors = 0

    def newGame(self):
        while True:
            user = str(input('Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors ')).lower()
            if (len(user) < 1 or user[0] not in self.choices):
                self.errors += 1
                if (self.errors > 3):
                    return                
                continue

            break;

        self.errors = 0

        machine = choice(list(self.choices.keys()))
        results = self.whoWins(self.choices[user], self.choices[machine])

        self.score[results] += 1            

    def whoWins(self, userChoice, machineChoice):
        if (userChoice == machineChoice):
            result = 'draws'
            print("It's a draw...\n")
        else:
            result = 'wins' if (userChoice, machineChoice) in self.winningCombos else 'losses'
            winMsg = 'Congrats! {0} beats {1}\n'.format(userChoice, machineChoice)
            losMsg = 'Better luck next time...{1} beats {0}\n'.format(userChoice, machineChoice)

            print(winMsg if result == ['wins', 1] else losMsg)            
        return result

    def whatsTheScore(self):
        results = [(k,v) for k, v in self.score.items()]
        results.sort(reverse=True)
        for k,v in results:
            print('...{0:<6}: {1:>3}'.format(k, v))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = RockPaperScissors()

    result = input('Do you want to play a game? enter y or n ')
    if result.lower() == 'y':
        game.newGame()

        while True:
            result = input('Do you want to play again? enter y or n ')
            if result.lower() != 'y':
                break
            game.newGame()

        print('Final score is:')
        game.whatsTheScore()
        print('Thanks for playing!!')
    else:
        print('Please play again! Later!!')
```